# Is my password database encryption flow secure?

Tags: encryption, tls, passwords, salt, database

I'm not an expert and I would be very glad if someone could take a look at it and tell if there are any problems with it

Things I know/think are problematic

- using base64 digest + getting the first 32 char reduces key size, right?
- where should the salt be generated and stored
- should the encryption include some kind of counter
- should the aes IV be new each time the vault is encrypted?

Here are the diagrams of getting/setting the password file from and to the server:
Blue values are input by the player in a prompt
orange values are stored in a file on the client after authentication (not included in the diagrams)

[image: getting the vault]

[image: setting the vault]

Comment: Can you explain the rationale for the SHA256/base64 digest/first 32 characters part?

Comment: @ModalNest The aes function needs exactly 32 bytes key size, therefore the "first 32 chars", the base64 is just a random hash digest I chose (which is wrong, I should instead just use the raw hash bytes instead of a digest like base64 or hex)